# demo application for user requirement specification

Tags: c#, windows, gridview, user-interface, treeview

I have to create a user requirements specification for an application. I will need treeviews, menus, gridviews (with data). What is the quickest way to do this with little or no code and no database data. The application would need to react as almost if it was the final product. My initial thoughts is to programatically populate the treeview and gridview from xml files so i can change without any coding.
Does this make sense or what do other people do?

Comment: Well, i don't know the complexity of your GUI and how "precise" your mockup must be. But when we in our teams do mockups, methods range from quickly hacking something together with VisualStudio's designer (preferably .NET WPF or WinForms, even if the GUI should later be realized in C++/wxWidgets) to photoshopping several UI elements and building interactive demo in Powerpoint (we even had a mockup that was based on scanned hand-drawn sketches...) -- choose whatever methods suits _YOU_ best and allows you to get results quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application would need to react as almost if it was the final
>   product.

I think your first step is to set more realistic expectations and explain (possibly to the stakeholders?) the difference between a demo and a full product. If you are going to put in all the effort to make it that close to the final product, then it's probably not a demo. You might as well release it as a "beta" version.

Why not take a step back and create wireframes in a tool like Balsamiq and a simple functional spec in a Word document, Google docs or a Wiki? That can be created in a comparatively small amount of time and will give you a much better foundation to build the actual product or, at least, take a step further and create a demo with limited functionality.